# XPath2: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string()

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have this xml that contains certificates and its attributes. Here is the xml over which I am running the extraction query

```
<Certificates>
    <CertificateAndChain>
        <Certificate>
            <FriendlyName />
            <Thumbprint>EE8B375347FCADDC25547FDDF61866E07D5B6A71</Thumbprint>
            <SerialNumber>256BB11DB5BE889E46EBCD85608DA849</SerialNumber>
            <Version>3</Version>
            <SignatureAlgorithm>sha1RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
            <Issuer>CN=certname</Issuer>
            <Subject>CN=certname</Subject>
            <NotAfter>2040-09-26T18:30:00Z</NotAfter>
            <NotBefore>2016-09-27T18:30:00Z</NotBefore>
            <IsVerified>false</IsVerified>
        </Certificate>
```

.
.
.(continued)...

I have written another test over this xml that needs to extract thumbprints of all the certificates that are about to get expired in next 10 days.
As part of the test, , I have written the Extraction query as:

```
    <XPath2ResponseParameter Name="TPName"><ExtractionQuery><![CDATA[string(//CertificateAndChain/Certificate[NotAfter[text() <= (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D'))]]/Thumbprint)]]></ExtractionQuery></XPath2ResponseParameter>
```

The test is in xml file as well. However, when I run the test, I get this exception:
**A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string()**. 
This is probably happening because there are multiple certificate elements present in the xml. So, I couldn't figure out the way to extract all the thumbprints failing the mentioned condition(there could be more than 1 and I need to extract all of them)

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke function in axis when using XPath 2.0. So, try to move `string()` function to the end of the inner XPath (formatted for readability) :

```
//CertificateAndChain
 /Certificate[
    NotAfter[
        text() <= (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D'))
    ]
]/Thumbprint
 /string()
```

**UPDATE :**

Since CDATA can't receive multiple strings in this context, according to the error message in your first comment, then you need to combine those strings into one, presumably using [`string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) :

```
string-join(
    //CertificateAndChain
     /Certificate[
        NotAfter[
            text() <= (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D'))
        ]
    ]/Thumbprint
     /string()  
,' ')
```

Comment: <XPath2ResponseParameter Name="TPName"><ExtractionQuery><![CDATA[//CertificateAndChain/Certificate[NotAfter[text() <= (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D'))]]/Thumbprint/string()]]></ExtractionQuery></XPath2ResponseParameter>
I tried your soln. but it didn't work out. CDATA expects returntype to be string. Hope this didnt break that premise.

Comment: I tried this: <XPath2ResponseParameter Name="TPName"><ExtractionQuery><![CDATA[string(//CertificateAndChain/Certificate[NotAfter[text() <= (current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D'))]]/Thumbprint/string())]]></ExtractionQuery></XPath2ResponseParameter>

And again similar error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string() ("E8FDDC2BA4CAED4533DC6E14BA24CF...", "97AC511293A4207F2A8875B07B6928...", ...)